# What is the expression for kurtosis(X - Y)

Tags: probability-distributions

The skewness of the difference between two independent random variables, X and Y, is given by:

$$\text{skewness}(X-Y) = \frac{\mu _3(X) - \mu _3(Y)}{\big(\mu _2(X) + \mu _2(Y)\big)^{3/2}}$$

But what is the expression for kurtosis(X - Y)?

Comment: The standard deviation is a second order measure of the distribution of a data set. Skewness ( you mention in your question) is third order ... Kurtosis is fourth order ... read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis ... It fluctuates so sensitively that it does not appear to give a sensible measure of anything about the distribution

Comment: "It fluctuates so sensitively that it does not appear to give a sensible measure of anything about the distribution"

But does it follow it has no definite expression?

Answer (score 1):

If we write $Z=X-E[X]$, $W=Y-E[Y]$, then clearly $\mu_4(X-Y)=\mu_4(Z-W)$, while $E[Z]=E[W]=0$ and so $E[Z^n]=\mu_n$ and likewise for $W$. Then
$$ \mu_4(Z-W) = E[(Z-W)^4] = E[Z^4]-4E[Z^3]E[W]+6E[Z^2]E[W^2]-4E[Z]E[W^3]+E[Z^4] \\
= E[Z^4]+6E[Z^2]E[W^2]+E[Z^4] \\
= \mu_4(Z) + \mu_4(W) + 6\mu_2(Z)\mu_2(W), $$
by independence and linearity of expectation. Hence,
$$ \operatorname{kurt}{(X-Y)} = \operatorname{kurt}{(Z-W)} = \frac{\mu_4(Z) + \mu_4(W) + 6\mu_2(Z)\mu_2(W)}{(\mu_2(Z)+\mu_2(W))^2} \\
= \frac{\mu_4(X) + \mu_4(Y) + 6\mu_2(X)\mu_2(Y)}{(\mu_2(X)+\mu_2(Y))^2} $$